# What value to put for frameCapacity in AVAudioPCMBuffer initializer?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayernode, avaudiopcmbuffer

I'm making a metronome using `AVAudioEngine`, `AVAudioPlayerNode`, and `AVAudioPCMBuffer`. The buffer is created like so:

```
/// URL of the sound file
let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: <filename>, withExtension: "wav")!
/// Create audio file
let audioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: soundURL)
let audioFormat = audioFile.processingFormat
    
/// Create the buffer - what value to put for frameCapacity?
if let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: ???) {
    buffer.frameLength = audioFrameCount
    try? audioFile.read(into: buffer)
        
    return buffer
}
```

What value do I put for frameCapacity in the AVAudioPCMBuffer initializer?

The documentation says frameCapacity should be "The capacity of the buffer in PCM sample frames." What does that mean? Is this a static value or do you grab it from the audio file?

Answer (score 0):

`frameCapacity` is the maximum number of frames that `AVAudioPCMBuffer` can hold. You don't have to use all of the frames. Consumers of `AVAudioPCMBuffer`s should only ever consult `frameLength` frames, and `frameLength <= frameCapacity`.
A capacity different from the length can be useful if you're processing audio in chunks of `N` frames, and for whatever reason you get a short read:

```
let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: N)

while readChunk(chunk) {
    let frameLength = min(buffer.frameCapacity, chunk.lengthInFrames)
    // copy frameLength frames into buffer.floatChannelData[0] or something
    buffer.frameLength = chunkLength // could be less than N
}
```

But if you're only ever going to store `audioFrameCount` frames (the length of your file?) in the buffer, then set `frameCapacity` to that:

```
let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: audioFrameCount)
```

Comment: Thank you, and how do you get the audioFrameCount from the file?

Comment: I thought you already had that because provided `audioFrameCount`, but you can get the length from the `AVAudioFile` `length` field.